# How to do a Mockito Unit Testing on ViewModel in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mvvm, mockito, viewmodel

I am so clueless of my submission with is the Mockito Unit Testing for the Live Data from the ViewModels in Kotlin language. Here are some codes. I hope that I could test the live data from inside of the viewmodel using verify on change with observers.

```
class NextMatchViewModel : ViewModel() {

val nextMatchList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Events>>()

fun setNextMatchList(id: Int) {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.thesportsdb.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

    api.getNextMatch(id).enqueue(object : Callback<EventsArray> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<EventsArray>, response: Response<EventsArray>) {

            val results = response.body()
            val eventsList: ArrayList<Events>?
            eventsList = results!!.events as ArrayList<Events>?

            nextMatchList.postValue(eventsList)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<EventsArray>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("ysuf", "onFailure " + t.message)
        }

    })
}

fun getLiveData(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Events>> {
    return nextMatchList
 }
}
```

Thank you very much for the answer !